# How do i know to which graph i'm plotting?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

```
data1 = load('data1.mat')
data2 = load('data2.mat')
```

by doing `plot(val(1, :))` i have a graph but I don't know if it corresponds to data 1 or data 2 how can I choose the data in plots?

the second question is how can I concatenate data1 and data 2 basically let's say data1 is 1 2 3 and data2 is 4 5 6 the expected outcome would be :

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

then plot them both in the same figure?

Comment: Start a fresh MATLAB session, then type in the two `load` commands, then do `plot(val(1, :))`. You'll get an error, because `val` doesn't exist. Do you have a variable `val` in the MAT file? If yes, then after these load commands you'll have `data1.val` and `data2.val`. It should be clear which one you are plotting.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague. For the first part, you don't seam to be plotting anything inside `data1`, as you would if you were doing `plot(data1.val(1,:))`, for example. If `data1.mat` contains a variable `val`, you could save the different values for `val` coming from different .mat files in temporary storage and then concatenate. How to do it will depend on what type of variable `val` is. For example:

```
load('data1.mat');
temp = val;
load('data2.mat');
full_val = cat(1,temp,val);
```

Hope it helps, but as I said, question is a bit unclear.

Comment: That did the trick for the most part, only part left is how can i draw the graph of the data1 and data2 in the same figure? i tried `plot(full_val(1, :))` but got the following error `Error using plot
Not enough input arguments.`

Comment: Can you give something more complete (take a look at [this] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))? What does full_val now contain? If you are new to matlab, you can try a few things, like just printing the variable by writing it in the command line, using `whos [variable]`, or using the variable explorer. The answer to your question will depend on what `val` and `full_val` are.

Comment: Note the the funtion I used `cat(1...)` concatenates the given variables on the _first_ dimmension, so if you have for example `a = [1,2,3]` and `b = [4,5,6]` depending on weather you use  'cat(1,a,b)` or `cat(2,a,b)`, you will get a 1x6 vector or a 2x3 matrix.

Comment: data1 = load('data1.mat')
data2 = load('data2.mat')  then full_val = cat(2,temp,val); now i want the graph corresponding to data1 and data2 on the same figure as in i want the plots over each other. I mean i could simply do it using plot(data.val(1,:));hold on; plot(data2.val(1,:)) but what if i have 15 graphs i just want a methods that draws all the graphs in a matrix

Comment: Matlabs `plot` lets you input a matrix, and will plot each column as a separate dataseries. So, you can collect all your `datai.val` into a `full_val` matrix of size [lenth(val)x(amount of data)], and the just do `plot(full_val)`, or do everything in a for loop where you load the data, plot it and, if you don't need it anymore, overwrite it. Sidenote: mathworks is your best friend.

Comment: Kindly note plot(full_val) keeps giving me the error Error using plot
Not enough input arguments. i'd like you to, if possible add all the steps leading to this one in the answer to be sure i'm not doing something wrong thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd like to, but I really can't given the lack of information regarding the data type, size and such. _What is_ your val? You can use for example `size(val)` or `size(full_val)` to find out.

Comment: size(val) is 1 50, size(full_val) is 2 1

Comment: Then `cat` didn't work properly (or rather wasn't implemented properly). My last attempt is: `data1 = load('data1.mat'); data2 = load('data2.mat'); full_val = [data1.val , data2.val]; plot(full_val)'. The `[ ]' encasing arrays concatenate said arrays, the same way `cat()` does. `[a , b]` concatenates `a` and `b` along the first dimension, and `[a ; b]` along the second one.